# iPhone : How to display a common button on my all view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to put button which should be displayed on my all view.

The way we are implementing Tab Bar. I want to implement buttons.

Where should I put that button ? And where should I give its functionality ?

Comment: This depends a lot on the structure of your app. Why not just have a button class and instantiate it frim each view controller?

Comment: @PengOne : I can't keep it on each view Controller.

Comment: I am playing song on that button. And it should not change when view changes as the song may be coming from net using the buffering. So I want common functionality provided on each page.

Comment: Then I believe RRB's suggestion may be best, unless you wish to save the current state of the song in each view (doesn't seem like a grand idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your button on main window (i.e. UIWindow) and keep front always after when you loading view.

Comment: I don't find any option like keep front. !!

Answer (score 0):

How many views are we talking about?

If we're just talking about a few views, it probably makes sense to just include similar-looking buttons on each view. If we're talking about many views, then you'll probably want to look at other options.

One solution would be to create a subclass of UIViewController that sets up the button and contains the button's action. The controllers for each view would then be subclasses of that class, so that each inherits the button and action.